# Docker - Is it possible to create an IPv6-only bridge network?

Tags: networking, docker, ipv6

Is it possible to create a custom bridge network that only has IPv6 address?

When I try to create a custom bridge network in the following way:

```
docker network create --driver bridge --ipv6 --subnet 2001:db8:2::/64 mybridge
```

And inspect the created network I get:

```
[
{
    "Name": "mybridge",
    "Id": "b09351a7b7b4936bc0b3fdc7627d4a13ef3260d3f914ae347756f6358ab3a27d",
    "Created": "2019-02-26T11:41:37.261479401Z",
    "Scope": "local",
    "Driver": "bridge",
    "EnableIPv6": true,
    "IPAM": {
        "Driver": "default",
        "Options": {},
        "Config": [
            {
                "Subnet": "172.19.0.0/16",
                "Gateway": "172.19.0.1"
            },
            {
                "Subnet": "2001:db8:2::/64"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Internal": false,
    "Attachable": false,
    "Ingress": false,
    "ConfigFrom": {
        "Network": ""
    },
    "ConfigOnly": false,
    "Containers": {},
    "Options": {},
    "Labels": {}
}
```

]

And when I run a container it gets IPV4 address:

```
root@ip-10-0-3-167:/home/ubuntu# docker run -d --net mybridge redis
75fac838472a94519f30e2bdbcc10403a7a952fce285ee5d258fd87f0773f618

"Containers": {
        "75fac838472a94519f30e2bdbcc10403a7a952fce285ee5d258fd87f0773f618": {
            "Name": "cocky_tesla",
            "EndpointID": "b2940a158646e4343564668abeb98aac519238d8a471dce26ee8e0f76a5c38e4",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:02",
            "IPv4Address": "172.19.0.2/16",
            "IPv6Address": "2001:db8:2::2/64"
        }
```

Additional info:
I'm using Ubuntu server 16.04 EC2 instance, Docker version 18.09.2

Comment: what happens if you remove IPv4 info from config files?

Comment: @TJJ how is that exactly done?

Comment: @Ferrybig I don't remember. I ditched docker because of its lousy IPv6 support.